# Weather visualization from csv data files

Tags: opengl, visualization

I'm preparing for a project related to weather visualization. I have some .csv files (100 rows, 120 colums) that contain weather data measured in my country where each cell represents a point with some specific values e.g. temperature or wind speed. Those files may be perceived as sets of points of latitude and longitude that covers my whole country (in fact the values are measured every 5 miles). I'd like to transformed the data and put the values on maps to make some weather visualizations, both 2d and 3d, especially heatmaps or hightmaps. I'm wondering which technology is the best for that. I was thinking of openGL, but all the textures mapping and drawing operations seem a bit difficult to me (but maybe they're not). I'm also considering making Java applets but there are many Java graphics libraries and I don't know wich one is the best for my requirements. Maybe all those things are possible to do in XNA, whcih would be great, because I'm programming mainly in C#. I'd be glad if some more experienced programmers could recommend me an appropriate language and libraries. What would you use to make the work easy and efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL is just the pencil and paper for program to draw things with. While it certainly is possible to use OpenGL for this, I strongly suggest using an off the shelf visualization tool, like Origin, Matlab Visualization, visualization modules of R, etc.

If you're more looking in the direction of a visualization programming toolkit, have a look at VTK http://www.vtk.org/

But naked OpenGL for that task: Only recommendable if you "speak OpenGL fluently".

Comment: Thanks for the VTK. It seems like a great choice for what I need.